# Single td with border CSS

Tags: css, html-table, border

```css
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin:100px auto;
    }
    
 td {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        border:1px solid #080808;
    }
    
.border {
        border: 1px solid #080808;
    }

    
.noborders td {
        border:0;
    }

      
.border_single {

        border: 1px solid #080808;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody class="border">
        <tr>
            <td>Table Cell with borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell with borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell with borders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborders">
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborders">
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td class="border_single">Table WITH border</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to understand how CSS passes values across a table hierarchy. I've purposely classed a td as "border_single" in order to specifically reference it and apply a basic border. I cant get the border to show, I'm assuming its inheriting the styles from high levels which is why the border for the specific td isnt showing?

Comment: pay attention to specifity, as you have a specifity issue .. try this `td.border_single `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct, you just need to add td in your class

```
.border_single 
{
   border: 1px solid #080808;
}
```

to this

```
td.border_single 
{
   border: 1px solid #080808;
}
```

Even if you have `td.no_borders`,`td.with_background` and more,  the `td.border_single` will still work as specified, you can also use id `#border_single` or `td#border_single` to be more specific.

You can also use td:nth-child(n), td:first-child, td:last-child and have the same output, without using id or class

```css
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin:100px auto;
    }
    
 td {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        border:1px solid #080808;
    }
    
.border {
        border: 1px solid #080808;
    }

    
.noborders td {
        border:0;
    }

      
td.border_single {

        border: 1px solid #080808;
    }
    
tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(2)
    {
    border: 1px solid #080808;
    }
tr:last-child > td:nth-child(2)
    {
    border: 1px solid #080808;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody class="border">
        <tr>
            <td>Table Cell with borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell with borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell with borders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborders">
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborders">
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td class="border_single">Table WITH border</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborders">
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborders">
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>With border using tr:nth-child(n) > td:nth-child(n)</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborders">
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborders">
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>With border using tr:last-child > td:nth-child(n)</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Specificity is important in CSS declaration.

The selectors win in the order of:

1. Importance (by using `!important`)
2. Specificity
3. Source order

Read more [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance)

`.no_borders td` is more specific than `.border_single`, so in:

```
    <tr class="noborders">
        <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        <td class="border_single">Table WITH border</td>
        <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
    </tr>
```

`<td class="border_single">Table WITH border</td>` will pick up the style from `.no_borders td` instead of `.border_single`.

---

### Solution

One possible solution is to use `id` instead of `class` selector as `id` is more specific than `class`.

In this case, use `<td id="border_single">` in your HTML file and change `.border_single` to `#border_single` in your CSS file. You can run the snippet below to see how it works.

```css
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin:100px auto;
    }
    
 td {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        border:1px solid #080808;
    }

.border {
        border: 1px solid #080808;
    }

.noborders td {
        border:0;
    }
      
#border_single {
        border: 1px solid #080808;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody class="border">
        <tr>
            <td>Table Cell with borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell with borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell with borders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborders">
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="noborders">
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
            <td id="border_single">Table WITH border</td>
            <td>Table Cell without borders</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!